# Java sqlite performing thousands of queries

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a java program where I perform thousands of queries on a SQLite database inside a loop. If the query shows up empty, then I insert the row. If the query has a result, I ignore. I generally perform these individual queries in batches of 1000, but in the end there will be some hundreds of thousands of total queries to finish this task.

Because I have thousands of lines that I'm checking with individual queries, this portion of the program runs very slowly.

Is there a more efficient way to perform this many queries?

Here is the loop that constantly pulls the original data from excel docs until all the information is read:

```
for(int i =0;i < batchSize;i++){
     try {
        String[] rowReader=(dataRows.get(i));
        archiveID=rowReader[16];
        DIVA = rowReader[41];

        //Check if already in DB. If it is not, then adds to a batch
        System.out.println("checking db");
        if(!isInDB(conn, archiveID, DIVA)){ 
            stmt.setString(1,archiveID);
            stmt.setString(2,DIVA);
            stmt.setString(3,docName);
            stmt.addBatch();
        }

    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        endOfDoc = true;
    }

    //dump to database every batchSize
    if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
        //System.out.println("executing batch");
        stmt.executeBatch();
        conn.commit();
        count=0;
    } 
}
```

Here is the actual query method:

```
//returns false if combo is not in All Records, returns true if there
public static boolean isInDB(Connection conn, String archiveID, String DIVA) throws SQLException {
    Connection c = conn;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

      stmt = c.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM AllRecords WHERE ArchiveID=\"" + archiveID +"\" AND DivaCat=\""+DIVA +"\"" );
      if ( rs.next() ) {
         return true;
      }else{
          System.out.println(archiveID+DIVA+" is not in DB");
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          return false;

      }
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    return false;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Reuse `stmt`. Do you have indexes?

Comment: @VHS The queries are too slow for well over 100,000 individual queries. How can I speed that up?

Comment: @CL. I don't have any indexes setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any index, finding the desired row(s) requires that the database goes through the entire table, for each query execution.

You can optimize the lookup in this particular query by indexing both lookup columns:

```sql
CREATE INDEX whatever ON AllRecords(ArchiveID, DivaCat);
```

Comment: Thanks! MASSIVE speed increase.

Answer (score 0):

Your isInDB method connect to database each time. You dont need it. You can do that with just one query too.

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM AllRecords WHERE "

for(int i =0;i < batchSize;i++){
    ...
    if(i ==0)
        sqlQuery + = "ArchiveID=\"" + archiveID +"\" AND DivaCat=\""+DIVA +"\""; 
    else
        sqlQuery + = " OR ArchiveID=\"" + archiveID +"\" AND DivaCat=\""+DIVA +"\"";
```

after that execute sqlQuery query and check your each row with rs results.

Comment: Probably should use a StringBuilder for this